# Getting NoClassDefFoundError on using JapaneseTokenizer of Apache Lucene 7.1.0

Tags: java, lucene, kuromoji

I am trying to use the JapaneseTokenizer from Apache Lucene 7.1.0. Its giving me `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/lucene/analysis/ja/JapaneseTokenizer` and `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.lucene.analysis.ja.JapaneseTokenizer`. Although, all other analyzers and tokenizers from Lucene(like StandardAnalyzer, etc.) work perfectly fine. How to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if there are any conflicting libs in classpath?